# Accelerate the Execution of queries .net

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I want to create blogs by create around 10 tables and insert huge data the problem is that this work fine for create a few number of blogs but if we want to create 1500 it works like a snail.

```
  private void createBlog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < Blogs_dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
       {
        bool IscommentCreated = MySQL.CreateComments(blogList);
        if (IscommentCreated)
        {
            MySQL.InsertIntoComments(blogList);
        }
        //===========Part2=========================================
        MySQL.Createlinks1(blogList);
        MySQL.Createlinks2(blogList);
        MySQL.Createlinks3(blogList);
        MySQL.Createoptions(blogList);
        MySQL.InsertIntooptions(blogList, mail, getePermalink());
        //other tables are inserted here
       }
    }
```

I have tried to union between many steps of creation and this accelerate the execution little bit but not too much

How can I accelerate the execution?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Are you creating 10 tables per blog?

Comment: you can share what you tried ? :)

Comment: @Mitch Yes Exactly this is what I mean

Comment: @POHH ok I will add a part of code

Comment: Typically you would just add a `BlogID` column and use the same tables for all Blogs.

Comment: You'd need to share the code of the `MySQL` class. Assuming it uses ADO.NET, a common pitfall is creating and disposing the `IDbCommand` object for each individual query.

Comment: I can't change the db

Comment: @C.Evenhuis yes ADO.net  [code] MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryall, conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common pitfall when using ADO.NET is not reusing the `IDbCommand` objects:

```
public class X
{
    public void PerformQuery(...)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            // create parameters and parameter values
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, it could look a bit like this:

```
public class X : IDisposable
{
    public MySqlCommand cmdInsertThings;
    public MySqlCommand cmdInsertOtherThings;
    public bool disposed; 

    public X(MySqlConnection c)
    {
        cmdInsertThings = c.CreateCommand();
        // create parameters
        cmdInsertOtherThings = ...
    }

    public void PerformQuery(...)
    {
        // assign parameter values
        cmdInsertThings.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (disposed) return;
        disposed = true;
        cmdInsertThings.Dispose();
    }
}
```

(And of course you have to keep the `MySqlConnection` open throughout the entire operation, I assume you already do)